# Get Attribute in svg path Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the attributes, either `aria-label` or `fill`, fromthe following html code

```
<span class="fr66n">
<button class="wpO6b " type="button">
   <div class="QBdPU ">
      <span class="">
        <svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
         </svg>
      </span> 
   </div>
</button>
</span>
```

I tried using the `get_attribute("fill")`  call but it prints `None`, so I am not sure how else to do it

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fr66n")
button.get_attribte("fill")
```

If I call `click()` on button object, it presses it, so I am sure I am calling the right element

Comment: You are currently in the span class might want to xpath to the svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should xpath down to the svg element

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fr66n")
elem=button.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']")
print(elem.get_attribute("fill"))
```

Comment: I copied what you did, and I got a traceback error, unable to locate selector: "//svg" and also tried `button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/section/div/div[2]/div/article[1]/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div/span/svg")` `print(button.get_attribute("fill")`

Comment: Try this fix out.